# iOS launch images file type

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm working on an iPad app and reading [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc) that said launch images must be in PNG format, but in their iOS Human Guidelines, they only recommend to use .png, not "a must".
I want to use .jpg format as my launch images because  my launch images size in .png are about 2 mb alone, and only 90 kb in .jpg format.
Thanks

Comment: Rule of thumb - If it says it in the docs, it is true!

Comment: New doc doesn't say PNG anymore: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify in the Info.plist the UILaunhImageFile field

```
    <key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
    <string>Default.jpg</string>
```

Setting this information will make the system look for Default.jpg and all its variations (portait, landscape, @2x, etc) instead of .png

for example, I'm coding an Universal app, and now all the launch images are .jpg, including iPad Retina: Default-Portrait@2x.jpg

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. You can change the name of your file but not the extension. Not if you develop for iphone5: "Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images." Quote from official email from Apple, sent when rejecting my app for using jpg files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true. Even if you find some workaround (e.g. just renaming the jpeg file to "Default.png"), since it is documented that it must be PNG then Apple is free to make your workaround stop working at any time.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, but in [iOS Human Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5) they only recommend to use .png, not "a must". Which one is correct?

Comment: @dreamexploded: The statement in the HIG is a general statement about all images. The "App Store icon" may be a jpeg, and you can use whatever format you can load into a UIImage for toolbar, navigation bar, and tab bar icons.